# Question about 32-bit / 64-bit systems

Tags: operating-system, platform, bit

Firstly, what is this called? Is this the system's "platform"? If I want to know if a system is 32-bit or 64-bit, do I ask what "platform" it is?

Next, is what I wrote below correct:

-A 64-bit processor can run a 64-bit operating system or a 32-bit operating system (with a loss of efficiency).

-A 32-bit processor can run a 32-bit operating system only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I want to know if a system is 32-bit or 64-bit, do I ask what "platform" it is?

"Platform" is an overloaded term that can mean a great many things.  It can mean the CPU family: x86 platform, IA-64 platform, x86-64 platform, ARM platform, MIPS platform, SPARC platform, etc.  It can mean the underlying operating system: Windows platform, Linux platform, Solaris platform, etc.  It can mean a combination of these: Wintel platform (Windows + Intel).  It can mean specific distributions: Debian platform, Slackware platform.

If you want to know if a system is 32-bit or 64-bit, ask if it's 32-bit or 64-bit.  And make sure that you also check the CPU for compatibility for your purposes.  ARM cores are 32-bit too, but you can't run Windows on them (at this time).  SPARCs can be 64-bit, but you won't be running your copy of Microsoft Office on it, I'd wager.

> A 64-bit processor can run a 64-bit operating system or a 32-bit operating system (with a loss of efficiency).

This depends very much on the processor.  Intel's IA-64 chips can't run 32-bit operating systems because they don't really have 32-bit instructions (if memory serves).  About the only way you could run a 32-bit OS on one is if you emulated a 32-bit CPU of some sort.  This would suck performance-wise.

On the other hand the x86-64 chips can run 64-bit OSes or 32-bit OSes with no loss of performance at all for the latter (when compared to a pure x86, I mean).  I'm running a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, for example, on an x86-64 chip without difficulties.  Of course the 64-bit system will run faster than the 32-bit *if the underlying software was written to take advantage of the expanded capabilities*!  (You'd be surprised how little it matters for most day-to-day tasks, though.)

> A 32-bit processor can run a 32-bit operating system only.

Again, it all depends on the processor.  An x86 (not x86-64) can run 32-bit OSes, but can also run 16-bit OSes right down to plain old MS-DOS.  On the other hand, ARMs tend to be 32-bit only.  (There are some ARM cores that have 16-bit instructions, but most do not, again if memory serves.)

Comment: Windows CE runs fine on ARM processors.  Also most ARM processors support 16-bit Thumb instructions, but these are just compressed versions of 32-bit instructions, the datapath and pointers are all still 32 bits.  Unlike x86 processors, ARMs don't have variable-length instructions, so Thumb mode is provided to make better use of i-cache.

Comment: Windows CE is not Windows.  It shares almost none of the code base of the Windows NT line nor of any earlier Windows line.  It is a modular RMX that contains the word "Windows" in its name for marketing purposes.

(*Anti*-marketing these days, it seems, but still.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd strike the part about "with a loss of efficiency".  64 bit processors can run 32 bit OS's just fine; with exception to Itanium which require special OS builds.

Efficiency has nothing at all to do with it.

Comment: There is a loss of efficiency, not necessarily compared to a 32-bit processor running the same code, but compared to 64-bit code which takes advantage of the more numerous registers.

Comment: The code can only take advantage of those registers if it is written to do such.  If it's not, ie: running a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit processor, then there is no loss.

Answer (score 2):

To give a partial answer: 32-bit or 64-bit is part of the *architecture*. I guess it is part of the platform too, but you're more likely to make an expert think of the 32/64-bit distinction by talking about architecture.

Honestly, if you want to know whether a system is 32-bit or 64-bit, just ask, "32-bit or 64-bit?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we mean on bare metal, the second statement is true. The verity of the first depends on the processor architectures. IA-64 processors cannot run IA-32 operating systems without emulation, whereas EM64T processors can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a system is 32-bit or 64-bit, you could ask what "bitness" it is.

Whether the statements about 64-bit and 32-bit processors running 64-bit and 32-bit operating systems are true depends entirely on which processors and operating systems you are talking about. You won't have much success running Windows XP on an 64-bit Alpha or SPARC processor.

Comment: "Bitness"?  That's... a new term to me.